# $\forall a > 0$, can $\{ x < -a \text{ or } x > a \}$ be rewritten as $\{ -a > x > a \}$?

Tags: notation

While studying about inequalities, I came across the following definition ($\forall a > 0)$:

$$
\begin{alignat}{1}
  & |x| > a \iff \{ x \mid x < -a \text{ or } x > a \} \\
  & |x| < a \iff \{ x \mid -a < x < a \}
\end{alignat}
$$

Naturally, as $\{ -a < x < a \}$ could be rewritten as $\{ -a < x \text{ and } x < a \}$, I wonder if is valid to rewrite $\{ x < -a \text{ or } x > a \}$ as $\{ -a > x > a \}$.

I don't know if that would be valid because, while $\{ -a < x < a \}$ represents only one interval, $\{ -a > x > a \}$ would represent two in a single expression. Is that notation valid?

Comment: No. Combining the inequalities implies that they both hold.

Comment: Where did you find that defintion? It seems to involve gross abuse of set notation.

Comment: as it is, and != or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On the number line, inequalities are, by construction,
   **transitive**. [So](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)#Transitivity), $$\forall a, b, c\in\mathbb R,\quad[(a<b\; \text{ and }\; b<c)\implies a<c].$$

   For $a>0,$ the statement $$-a > x > a$$ is therefore false, since, by
   transitivity, it implies that $a<-a,$ which is a contradiction.
2. More to the point:  $$-a > x > a$$ [actually reads as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)#Chained_notation) $$x<-a\; \text{
   AND }\; x>a$$ instead of as the intended $$x<-a\; \text{ OR }\; x>a.$$

Comment: $-a > x > a$ **is** well-formed (given the usual convention that it means $-a > x \land x > a)$. It is false if $>$ is given its usual arithmetic interpretation, but that does not mean that it is logically ill-formed. Please be more careful about your use of logical terminology, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the double inequality $-a > x > a$ implies in particular $-a > a$, which is a rather strange property for a positive number, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, I totally agree, thank you for the answer. :) Do you have any reference to that statement?